# Toastr "options" don't work

Tags: javascript, toastr

I create notification message using Toastr. My notification message is shows, but I can't use any options, I put some options but they don't work.

```js
$('#editButton').click(function() {
  toastr.success('System successfully saved');
  toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
  toastr.options.positionClass = toast - top - center;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="button" id="editButton" type="submit" aria-hidden="true">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toast displays when you call `success()`. So you need to set your options before that.

Also toast-top-center is not a javascript identifier, it needs to be in quotes.

```
$('#editButton').click(function () {
    toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
    toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
    toastr.success('System successfully saved');
});
```

Comment: Cool it's works. Maybe you know, how I can add styles to this notification? For example: bg-color.

Comment: toasts have a css class according to their type `toast-warning`, `toast-info` etc. Just override the css for those classes in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> toastr.options.positionClass = toast-top-center;

You forgot the quotes.

```
toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-top-center";
```